# Can't use Fingerprint Reader on my HP Envy 13

Tags: drivers, usb, hp

Recently switched from win11 to Ubuntu and I can't find the option to enable fingerprint reader on my device:

using `lsusb` bring the following results

`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface`

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:7090 Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wide Vision HD Camera`

`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

how do I go about enabling the fingerprint drivers

Comment: There does not appear to be a fingerprint reader in your list of devices. Generally speaking, though, the readers on HP devices do not have a great track record for Linux support. 95% of all fingerprint readers are Windows-only devices because the manufacturers do not share technical details about the hardware. As a result, nobody can write drivers. The drivers that do exist were mostly reverse engineered by people fed up with waiting for a driver that never materialises 

Comment: @matigo thanks... didn't know that